# why in view page 'object' does not contain a definition for 'surveyTitle'?

Tags: c#

This is my code bellow:

```
var data = (from s in surveys
           join sp in sps on s.Id equals sp.SurveyId
           select new
                      {  
                        surveyId = s.Id,
                        surveyTitle = s.Title,
                        surveyStatus = sp.Status
                        }).GroupBy(g=>g.surveyId).Select(x=>x.First());
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide more code and the actual error / inner exception. You mentioned about view page, is it asp.mvc / winform / wpf? Please edit the question and add related tag and more error detail. The readers don't have enough information to help you. If I have to guess, it's `First` that causes the error, use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i rember you need to give a name to the "array"

```
select new SomeName {  
                    surveyId = s.Id,
                    surveyTitle = s.Title,
                    surveyStatus = sp.Status
                    }
```